# Can I add a surrogate key for a AWS redshift table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, surrogate-key

I need to create and unique row in the redshift table. so is there a possibility to add the surrogate key to the redshift table?

Comment: What is involved with adding a surrogate key to a table? Are you just talking about adding a column that with the `identity` attribute, or something else?

Comment: Not identity, like uniqueidentifier. I have to add uniqueidentifer but i says it cannot. any alternative suggestions for that?